# insertion sort theoretical analysis, total number of shifts.

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting

Given the following array:

```
[14 17 21 34 47 19 71 22 29 41 8]
```

and the following excerpt from the book Algorithms Unlocked by  Thomas Cormen
(slightly edited, [START] and [STOP] flags are not part of the text):

> Insertion sort is an excellent choice when the array starts out as
>   ''almost sorted''. **[START]** Suppose that each array element starts out within
>   k positions of where it ends up in the sorted array. Then the total
>   number of times that a given element is shifted over all iterations
>   of the inner loop is at most k. Therefore, the total number of times
>   that all elements are shifted over all inner-loop iterations, is at
>   most kn, which in turn tells us that the total number of inner-loop
>   iterations is at most kn (since each inner-loop iteration shifts
>   exactly one element by one position).**[STOP]** If k is a constant, then the
>   total running time of insertion sort would he only Θ(n), because the
>   Θ-notation subsumes the constant factor k. In fact we can even
>   tolerate some elements moving a long distance in the array, as long as
>   there are not too many such elements. In particular, if L elements can
>   move anywhere in the array (so that each of these elements can move by
>   up to n-1 positions), and the remaining n - L elements can more at
>   most k positions, then **the total number of shifts is** at most L * (n –
>   1) + (n – L) * k = (k + L) * n – (k + 1) * L, which is Θ(n) if both k
>   and L are constants.

The books is trying to explain how it crafts a formula, which it presents at the bottom of the text. I would like some help to better understand what it says, very likely, it could help a specific example using the above sample array, so that what is going on with the k and n variables. Can you help me to better understand the above excerpt's analysis?

To be more specific what is confusing me, the lines between [START] and [STOP] flags ,these are the lines:

> Suppose that each array element..... which in turn tells us that the
>   total number of inner-loop iterations is at most kn(since each
>   inner-loop iteration shifts exactly one element by one position).

(anything below these lines is totally understood all the way to the end.)

Answer (score 1):

Let is consider the insertion sort algorithm

**Algorithm: InsertionSort(A)**

```
i ← 1
while i < length(A)
    j ← i
    while j > 0 and A[j-1] > A[j]
        swap A[j] and A[j-1]
        j ← j - 1
    end while
    i ← i + 1
end while
```

The inner loop - move elements of A[0..i-1] one by one, till A[i] is in its correct position. 
Therefore if a given element is atmost k position away from its correct place, we will have a maximum of k compares and swaps. For n elements it will be k*n.

Hope it helps!